# Use WebCryptography API to get CryptoJS words

Tags: javascript, sha1, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

I am migrating function using Google's CryptoJS to browser native WebCryptography API.

With CryptoJS, I use the following code to get the words array of SHA1 hash

```
CryptoJS.SHA1('1w0g6Ixf2VHvOc+6pGBqDHItFYQ=:9590467').words
```

and it returns `[888149035, -1762573935, 1178769020, -1914057363, 481296384]`

With WebCrypto API, I use

```
const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode('1w0g6Ixf2VHvOc+6pGBqDHItFYQ=:9590467')
const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', msgBuffer);
const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
```

and `hashArray` is `[52, 240, 20, 43, 150, 241, 65, 145, 70, 66, 150, 124, 141, 233, 205, 109, 28, 176, 0, 0]`

How can I transform this result to the same array as CyptoJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would've been nice if were as simple as

```
const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode('1w0g6Ixf2VHvOc+6pGBqDHItFYQ=:9590467')
const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', msgBuffer);
const hashArray = Array.from(new Int32Array(hashBuffer));
```

except for endianness - so, it's just a little more complex

```js
async function test() {
    const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode('1w0g6Ixf2VHvOc+6pGBqDHItFYQ=:9590467')
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', msgBuffer);
    const dv = new DataView(hashBuffer);
    const hashArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < dv.byteLength; i+=4) {
        hashArray.push(dv.getInt32(i, false));
    }
    return hashArray;
};
test().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Indeed, everything in crypto-js is BE.

Comment: `getInt32(i, false)` - the false results in a bigendian "get" of a int32 from the dataview